# TextArea with string on top of another string

Tags: java, javafx

I Have a textArea that displays a string with a value. I have a button with an eventHandler attached. When I press this button, I want to add another string and new value (which adds to the prev value). I am using

textArea.appendText( " string" + cost);

But this is adding it next to the previous line in the textArea, but I want this line to be below it. I
have not been able to find a method to use instead of append. Is there a way to add the new line below?

Comment: use textArea.appendText( " string" + cost + "\n");

Comment: Thank you! this worked. And it is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append your text with an Escape Sequence("\n").
This should put the new line below it.

You can do something like this:

```
textArea.appendText("\n" + cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "\n" for new line, one each string that you want to be on a new line